# Customising a row of listview

Tags: android, listview, custom-lists

I am a newbie to android.
I am trying to develop this UI. This is a single row of listview.

I have tried diff ways but not able to this. [image]

Here in this pic, I know how to set that bubble background and use ninepatch and customise listview. 
What challenge for me is I want to display some text here after button. 
In case if the string is long i.e going to nextline than It should continue below the button.

Please suggest me how to move forward.

Should I use two textviews and check if the first textview is filled than further string should be displayed in the second textview or any other way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ArrayAdapter or BaseAdapter. Check out the following links

[most recommended](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)

[link](http://www.codelearn.org/android-tutorial/android-listview)

[tutorial1](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92)

[tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/)

[tuorial3](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/)

**EDIT:**

Use seperate Linear Layout for both the view. It should do the trick

Comment: thanks but I know customising listview. 
My problem is a long sentence being displayed the way it is shown in the pic.

Comment: @HarishVats the Whole text hi ... you want to be in one line

Comment: @HarishVats use android:maxLines="no of lines"

Comment: No.. First there is a button. Then a textview. 
As the line starts displaying in next line, It should start from just below the starting position of button. 
Usually it will appear below "hi," .. but we want text to display from the very beginning in next line.

Comment: If u can help here..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25601953/customlist-view-and-treeobserver

Comment: @HarishVats did it work what I suggested you for this current answer

Comment: NO... U were not able to get my question. U were talking about layout, 
but I wanted a method to display a single sentence, fitting into the two textviews. 

I have done it.